# Concrete5 CMS Page Type and Page Templates (defaulting to default.php)

Tags: php, templates, content-management-system, concrete5, concrete5-5.7

I have just got into a new clients office today to fix up a site using Concrete5 CMS, however I'm having an issue with something. (Never used this CMS before so think I've done OK so far).

Issue I'm facing is this:

1. I created 2 new page types: blog and blog article
2. I created 2 new page templates blog.php and blog_article.php
3. I assigned to the page types what templates to use as default

However when I view the the blog page or a blog article page it was not using the templates I found but always using default.php template.

Anyone have any ideas why this might be and why it is not using the page templates I assigned to the page types?

**UPDATE**

**blog_article.php**

```
<?php  defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die(_("Access Denied."));  ?>

<?php  $this->inc('elements/header.php'); ?>

<div class="ccm-page page-type-blog-article page-template-full">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-content">
                <?php
                    $a = new Area('Main');
                    $a->setAreaGridMaximumColumns(12);
                    $a->display($c);
                    print $innerContent; // testing
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3 col-sidebar">
                <?php
                    $a = new Area('Sidebar');
                    $a->display($c);
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<?php  $this->inc('elements/footer.php'); ?>
<?php  $this->inc('elements/footer-c5.php'); ?>
```

**blog_listing.php**

```
<?php  defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die(_("Access Denied."));  ?>

<?php  $this->inc('elements/header.php'); ?>

<div class="ccm-page page-type-blog page-template-full">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-content">
                <?php
                    $a = new Area('Main');
                    $a->setAreaGridMaximumColumns(12);
                    $a->display($c);
                    print $innerContent;
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3 col-sidebar">
                <?php
                    $a = new Area('Sidebar');
                    $a->display($c);
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<?php  $this->inc('elements/footer.php'); ?>
<?php  $this->inc('elements/footer-c5.php'); ?>
```

I have attached screenshots of the admin areas etc..

Hope someone can spot what im doing wrong, totally new to concrete5 and 2nd day on the job so need to make some good progress today haha

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you clear or turn off caching? What version of Concrete5?

Comment: Yep cache is off and cleared it to make sure, plus it is 5.7.2... from what i can remember.

Comment: Are the right templates listed when you click the pages in the Sitemap > Design & Type?

Comment: Yep, shows right one for Page Type and Page Template.....

Comment: Just updated question with some template code examples and also screenshots of the areas that might need to see. Thanks